# How to split the list according to some object inside it

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, java-stream

So, this is one method that takes user name and returns list of applications assigned to the user

```
public TransformedResponse getAppsList(String userName) throws BadRequestException, ConstraintViolationException
    {​​​​​​​
       ...
        else
        {​​​​​​​
            List<AppList> appsList = appDataRepository.findAll(checkUser);
            return transformer.transform(appsList);
        }​​​​​​​
    }​​​​​​​
```

The found list (appsList) is :

```
[
        {
            "applicationId": 1,
            "name": "Units",
            "description": "Units description",
            "category": "Main"
        },
        {
            "applicationId": 2,
            "name": "Devices",
            "description": "Devices description",
            "category": "Main"
        },
        {
            "applicationId": 5,
            "name": "Location",
            "description": "Location description",
            "category": "Others"
        },

]
```

So this is one method in the transformer class that mentioned above:

```
public TransformedResponse transform(List<AppList> appsList)
    {
        TransformedResponse transformedResponse = new TransformedResponse();
        transformedResponse.setData(appsList);
        return transformedResponse;
    }
```

So, the final result returned from transformer method:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "applicationId": 1,
            "name": "Units",
            "description": "Units description",
            "category": "Main"
        },
        {
            "applicationId": 2,
            "name": "Devices",
            "description": "Devices description",
            "category": "Main"
        },
        {
            "applicationId": 5,
            "name": "Location",
            "description": "Location description",
            "category": "Others"
        },
    ]
}
```

So what I need is I want to split that appsList according to the category i.e Main and Others so the result should be :

```
{
    "main": [
        {
            "applicationId": 1,
            "name": "Units",
            "description": "Units description",
            "category": "Main"
        },
        {
            "applicationId": 2,
            "name": "Devices",
            "description": "Devices description",
            "category": "Main"
        }
    ],

  "others":[ 
        {
            "applicationId": 5,
            "name": "Location",
            "description": "Location description",
            "category": "Others"
        },
    ]
}
```

The Transformed response class:

```
public class TransformedResponse
{
    public TransformedResponse()
    {
        super();
    }

    //private List<AppList> main;
    //private List<AppList> others;

    private List<AppList> data;

    public List<AppList> getData()
    {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(List<AppList> data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
    //public List<AppList> getMain()
    //{
    //    return data;
    //}
    //public void setMain(List<AppList> main)
    //{
    //    this.main = main;
    //}
    //public List<AppList> getOthers()
    //{
    //    return others;
    //}
    //public void setOthers(List<AppList> others)
    //{
    //    this.others = others;
    //}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with groupingBy:

```
Map<String, AppList> map = appsList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(AppList::getCategory));
```